# Spring JPA Entity table name from request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have multiple tables with the same schema. The only difference is the table name. Table names are in the format `table_name_<tenant_id>`, for example, `table_name_1`, `table_name_24`, `table_name_15` etc.,

I want to use a single Entity and JPA repository to perform operations on this table. I get the tenant_id from the Request. I want to execute queries on the corresponding tables.

How do I dynamically set the table name to be used for querying?

We have only 5 such tables since the data for each tenant is very high

*Not adding a MWE since I couldn't find any place to start trying approaches.*

Edit: Replace `user_id` with `tenant_id` and add number of tables present

Comment: why are you using this kind of approach (N tables with same structure) ? does not make any sense for me !

Comment: I am working with tables that were created a while back as part of a different system. The reasoning provided was that each user has a lot of data. So they went with this approach.

Comment: Take a look at this article, it seems exactly what you want: https://naveen.me/jpa-dynamic-table-name-entity/

Comment: Your question intrigued me; i wrote some stuff with native query and seems work, BUT with a huge limite, there will be NOT same PK across the table, else spring seems cache anyway !

Comment: For your current software the comment of @RolandoIsidoro is the correct answer. Over all please concider that physical splitt DB for each tenant is the best practice and in a lower sope multi-tenancy. It depends on your DB how that can be applied but it will work differnt than your appraoch and in a more clean structure. Both cases have better isolation and better access-right management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ronaldo Isidoro provided the solution in the comments

https://naveen.me/jpa-dynamic-table-name-entity/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating different Entity with different Table name create one entity ie:table_name and store the user_id as primary key and Using the JPA Repository fetch the details of the user using the findByUser_Id, so that we can normalize our database.

Comment: This is not a table I am creating now. This is a table that already exists. So I cannot change anything w.r.t the schema now.